# Wordpress pass post header & body to sendNotification.php

Tags: wordpress, firebase, post, http-post

I have an entire post notification system built using firebase.  Using a program like postman, I can send the title & body and the notifications show up on the iOS/android devices. So the entire linkage works.  Specifically in postman using the Post function, the URL posted too is https://example.com/backend/sendNotification.php.  The body code is:

```
{
  "title" : "post title",
  "body" : "post body"
}
```

But now I have to tie it into wordpress. The goal is that when a post is published, the title and body, most likely truncated to a limited amounts of characters, get passed to the URL.

I know the code will go in the function.php file, but beyond that I'm stumped.  How can I pass the title & body to the URL?

Comment: hai, if you want to add some code, I suggest you to build a plugin you can hook it to the post rather than changes the functions.php, because you will ruin the updates of your wordpress. you can read https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin to know wordpress plugin

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to hook into the post creation. There are several hooks that would probably fit your needs. Then use [wp_remote_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post) or curl to post your data to the webhook.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'push_post_data' );
function push_post_data( $data ) {

    if ('publish' == $data['post_status']) {
       wp_remote_post($url, $array_with_title_and body);

    }
}
```

If you're using a child theme or a custom theme functions.php is fine.